# codeigniter Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'length' in When theres additional segment

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter

I have this dependent dropdown. it works perfectly fine, but only when my url is

`baseurl/Class/function`

if i type some thing like `baseurl/Class/function/` or `baseurl/Class/function/data`

it will have an error of

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'length' in`

why is it? i try to create custom routes etc but it doesnt work.

i also tried doing `baseurl/Class/function?=data=$data`and it doest work also. i really need to pass value on the url, to make my other codes work, but this javascript doesnt work if i pass something to the url.

here is the js.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  $("#PROV_ID").change(function() {
    var PROVID = {"PROVID" : $('#PROV_ID').val()};
    console.log(PROVID);

    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      data: PROVID,
      url: "<?php base_url(); ?>Employees/dependent_dropdown/",

      success: function(data){
          var select = $('#CT_ID');
          select.html('');
          $.each(data, function(i, option){
              select.append("<option value='"+option.CT_ID+"'>"+option.CITY+"</option>");
          });
      }
     });
   });
  $("#PROV_ID2").change(function() {
    var PROVID2 = {"PROVID2" : $('#PROV_ID2').val()};
    console.log(PROVID2);

    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      data: PROVID2,
      url: "<?php base_url(); ?>Employees/dependent_dropdown2/",

      success: function(data){
          var select = $('#CT_ID2');
          select.html('');
          $.each(data, function(i2, option2){
              select.append("<option value='"+option2.CT_ID+"'>"+option2.CITY+"</option>");
          });
      }
     });
   });
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess $.each() method works with json object .Make sure your value is an object before you using $.each.

Comment: what about your routing rules

Comment: what routing rules

Comment: application/config/routes.php , inside this file you need to specify routing roules to accept parameters

Comment: for ex:    $route['controller/(:any)'] = 'controller/index/$1';

Comment: then? what will i do next?